# PowerShell - Get-Content - CreateFile sets dwShareMode to be FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE

Tags: .net, powershell

Is there any reason that when using **Get-Content -path file.txt**, the CreateFileW API parameters are:

```
dwDesiredAccess         GENERIC_READ
dwShareMode             FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE  
lpSecurityAttributes    NULL
dwCreationDisposition   OPEN_EXISTING
dwFlagsAndAttributes    FILE_FLAG_OPEN_NO_RECALL
```

If I use:
**[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines("file.txt")**

```
dwDesiredAccess         GENERIC_READ
dwShareMode             FILE_SHARE_READ
lpSecurityAttributes    NULL
dwCreationDisposition   OPEN_EXISTING
dwFlagsAndAttributes    FILE_FLAG_OPEN_NO_RECALL | FILE_FLAG_SEQUENTIAL_SCAN
```

Why is **FILE_SHARE_WRITE** set for a read? Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: In short: I don't know. Did you also try adding -RAW to get all lines as one string? Does that change results?

Comment: Because that way `Get-Content` can open and read files even when a non-exclusive writable file handle to the same file has been opened by another (or the same) process. Otherwise `Get-Content -Wait` would never work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The share mode parameter is used to indicate which types of shared concurrent accesses are acceptable to the caller - `Get-Content` is using `FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE` to tell the operating system "I don't care if anyone else wants to read or write to the file while I hold this file handle".

This is important when continously tailing a log file for example:

```
# imagine this is a log file
$tmpFile = New-TemporaryFile

$backgroundJob = Start-Job {
  param([string]$LiteralPath)

  1..10 |ForEach-Object {
    "Log entry $_" |Add-Content @PSBoundParameters

    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
  }
} -ArgumentList $tmpFile.FullName |Out-Null

# Tail the file and read the 10 log message as they roll in
$tmpFile |Get-Content -Wait |Select -First 10

$tmpFile |Remove-Item
```

If you run the code above, you'll observe that `Get-Content -Wait` is able to continuously read from the file even though we open it and write to it from the background job *10 times*.

This would *not* have been possible had the underlying file handle not been opened with `FILE_SHARE_WRITE`.

To observe this, let's take the same example and read from a file handle opened with *only* `FILE_SHARE_READ`:

```
$tmpFile = New-TemporaryFile

$backgroundJob = Start-Job {
  param([string]$LiteralPath)

  1..10 |ForEach-Object {
    "Log entry $_" |Add-Content @PSBoundParameters

    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
  }
} -ArgumentList $tmpFile.FullName

try {
  # OpenRead() will open the file with SHARE_READ
  $rfs = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($tmpFile.OpenRead())

  # Attempt to read the log lines, time out after 10 x 500ms
  $c = 10
  while(--$c){
    $line = $rfs.ReadLine()

    if($line -is [string]){
      Write-Host $line
    }
    else{
      # wait a little longer
      Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 500
    }
  }
}
finally {
  # clean up file reader
  $rfs |ForEach-Object Dispose
  $tmpFile |Remove-Item
}

# Fetch background job output, observe file access errors
$backgroundJob |Receive-Job -AutoRemoveJob -Wait
```

Instead of the log messages being displayed on the screen, you should expect to see the background job failing to log the messages to the file:

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\Users\irm\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpECB9.tmp' because it is being used by another
process.
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (C:\Users\irm\Ap...emp\tmpECB9.tmp:String) [Add-Content], IOException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetContentWriterIOError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddContentCommand
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

Comment: Thank you for the taking the time to provide examples.  Where you say: `This would not have been possible had the underlying file handle been opened with FILE_SHARE_WRITE.`.  Are you missing a 'not' in that statement?

Comment: @HelpingHand That's right, corrected.